# Where is Victor Fries' family from?

Tags: comics, dc, batman, the-new-52

In Batman Annual #1 (in the New 52 reboot), we see a few flashbacks to Victor Fries' (Aka Mr. Freeze) youth.  In one of them he is discussing building snowmen with his mother, and she responds by telling him how they built snowmen in "the old country". I took that as meaning that the Fries family are recent immigrants, but I can't find any reference to where they are from.

Do we know where Victor Fries is originally from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### You wouldn't be alone. DC has never revealed Victor Fries (Mr. Freeze) place of origin. Indeed when the character was first envisioned as Mr. Zero he didn't even have one. (Batman #121/3 (February 1959): "The Ice Crimes of Mister Zero") The Official Guide to the DC Universe lists him as an American citizen, nothing more.

He was meant to be a throw-away villain with a Freeze-ray. Since those days, he has become one of the main villains in Batman's rogue's gallery, yet we know almost nothing about him during his PreCrisis career, or his Post-Crisis one. His recent return in the DCnU has altered his history, (Nora is no longer his wife) but he is still nearly as much a mystery in the new universe. Our best guess is to use his last name as a potential point of origin, Fries can be either Danish or German.

Freeze has also been very much a staple of the animated Batman universes and each has a different voice and different accent including (Austrian, German, and Russian).

Comment: Not that a name is remotely definitive, but the name "Fries" identifies an ethnic minority in Northern Europe, today identified simply as German (I'm descended from these folks). Of course, the name is a pun, but I think it's reasonable to assume that he's German / Austrian: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Frisia.

Comment: Yup. Not Danish name. If it was Friis it would be Danish but Fries is not a Danish surname. I should know, I live in the darn country.

Comment: Sounds like a Dutch name. I don't know of any country besides The Netherlands where "Fries" is a common name.